Align vertices of different curves on one plane
I am currently trying to reconstruct a ship and have copied out a few frames of the hull as an example. I would like to use Bridge Edge Loops to generate surfaces between the vertices, which should represent the planks of the hull. Now I have the problem that the vertices lie at completely different spots on their curves and not on the same plane, so that the faces would not be straight later. I have already distributed the vertices evenly using LoopTools > Space, but unfortunately that didn't help either. Is there a way to align the vertices of the same spot of several curves all on one plane (so that they have the same value on the Z-axis)?
Thanks in advance!



You could simplify the edge loops a lot, also, do they have the same amount of vertices? Could you please share your file?

Sure and sry for the delay, I first had to learn how to share files: 

Unfortunately, the curves all have different lengths and so also different amounts of vertices. What do you mean by simplifying the edge loops? Sry I'm quite new to Blender and have very little experience with it.

First you delete the edges in the middle and separate each curve.
(P in edit mode, by loose parts)

Then you add these geometry nodes to make each curve have exactly 50 vertices (or another number you like).
Add the same geometry nodes to the three curves, and apply it for each.

Now in object mode select the three curves and join them (ctrl+J)
Now you can bridge loops because they have the same amount of vertices.
This is the result applying with 25 points:


Thanks Daniel, thats awesome! Didn't work till I double checked your instructions and realized I missed the APPLY part (just like you highligthed it^^). Thank you again!

You could select each edge loop and X Limited Dissolve, then increase the Max Angle value until you get the amount of vertices you want (example: 24), keep the same amount for each edge loop:

Then select all and right click > LoopTools > Loft:

And move each vertex along its edge until you get a cleaner topology:

